# How can I include the Jambase file to my build?

Tags: boost-build, bjam, jam, b2

I'm trying to setup a simple *bjam* build example, where I use the `SubDir` rule in my top-level `Jamroot.jam` file:

```
SubDir TOP ;

exe main : main.cpp ;
```

I'm using `boost_1_58_0` and when I leave out the `SubDir` directive, the build works fine.

But when I try to use `SubDir`, *bjam* claims that the rule is unknown...although I see that the `Jambase` file gets parsed:

```
dirkb@wks91:bjam_try$ BOOST_BUILD_ROOT=/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0 BOOST_ROOT=/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0 /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/engine/bin.linuxx86_64/b2 -f Jambase --debug-loading --debug-configuration
Parsing file: Jambase
notice: found boost-build.jam at /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/boost-build.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/boost-build.jam
notice: loading Boost.Build from /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/bootstrap.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/kernel/bootstrap.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/kernel/modules.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/kernel/modules.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/util/option.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/build-system.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/build/build-request.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/kernel/class.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/util/numbers.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/kernel/errors.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/util/sequence.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/util/assert.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/util/set.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/util/regex.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/build/feature.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/util/indirect.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/util/utility.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/build/property.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/util/path.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/util/string.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/util/container.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/tools/builtin.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/build/alias.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/build/project.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/util/print.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/build/scanner.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/build/property-set.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/build/virtual-target.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/build/type.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/build/generators.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/util/os.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/tools/common.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/build/toolset.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/util/order.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/build/targets.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/tools/stage.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/tools/types/register.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/tools/types/asm.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/tools/types/cpp.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/tools/types/exe.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/tools/types/html.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/tools/types/lib.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/tools/types/obj.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/tools/types/objc.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/tools/types/preprocessed.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/tools/types/qt.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/tools/types/rsp.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/tools/symlink.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/tools/message.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/tools/convert.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/tools/generate.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/build/configure.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/build/config-cache.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/tools/make.jam
Parsing file: /home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/build/version.jam
Initializing project 'test-config'
Assigned project target object(project-target)@62 to 'test-config'
Initializing project 'site-config'
Assigned project target object(project-target)@64 to 'site-config'
notice: Searching '/etc' '/home/dirkb' '/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src' '/usr/share/boost-build' '/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/kernel' '/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/util' '/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/build' '/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/tools' '/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/contrib' '/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/.' for site-config configuration file 'site-config.jam'.
notice: Configuration file 'site-config.jam' not found in '/etc' '/home/dirkb' '/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src' '/usr/share/boost-build' '/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/kernel' '/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/util' '/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/build' '/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/tools' '/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/contrib' '/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/.'.
Initializing project 'user-config'
Assigned project target object(project-target)@66 to 'user-config'
notice: Searching '/home/dirkb' '/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src' '/usr/share/boost-build' '/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/kernel' '/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/util' '/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/build' '/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/tools' '/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/contrib' '/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/.' for user-config configuration file 'user-config.jam'.
notice: Configuration file 'user-config.jam' not found in '/home/dirkb' '/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src' '/usr/share/boost-build' '/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/kernel' '/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/util' '/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/build' '/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/tools' '/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/contrib' '/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/.'.
Loading Jamfile at '.'
Initializing project 'Jamfile</disk2/stuff/dirkb/snaps/git/bjam_try>'
Assigned project target object(project-target)@68 to 'Jamfile</disk2/stuff/dirkb/snaps/git/bjam_try>'
Parsing file: Jamroot.jam
Jamroot.jam:1: in modules.load
ERROR: rule "SubDir" unknown in module "Jamfile</disk2/stuff/dirkb/snaps/git/bjam_try>".
/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/build/project.jam:325: in load-jamfile
/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/build/project.jam:64: in load
/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/build/project.jam:145: in project.find
/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/build-system.jam:535: in load
/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/kernel/modules.jam:289: in import
/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/kernel/bootstrap.jam:139: in boost-build
/home/dirkb/snaps/git/boost_1_58_0/boost-build.jam:17: in module scope
dirkb@wks91:bjam_try$
```

The `Jambase` file, and a simple `Jamrules`, exist at the top-level of my toy project. When I leave out the "`-f Jambase`" option, *bjam* picks the internal Jambase definition (+) but yields the same result...`SubDir` is unknown.

When I start *bjam* with the option "`-d 12`" I see that the `SubDir` rule from the `Jambase` gets properly scanned, but somehow it's not correctly bound, defined or whatever *bjam* usually does to make methods/rules "usable". 
As you can probably see from the used paths, I have only bootstrapped `b2` so `boost` isn't properly installed yet. For debugging, I also patched its sources a little bit, that's where the "`Parsing file...`" messages come from.

How can I properly "inject" the rule definitions from the `Jambase` file, such that they are known while parsing `Jamfile`s?

Comment: I just confirmed that adding the verbatim definition of `SubDir` from `Jambase` to my top-level `Jamfile`, makes the example work. So environment variables, paths and such appear to be setup correctly. It's all about somehow "verbatim include"ing the `Jambase` definitions, such that I don't have to mess up my root `Jamfile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**: If your project contains Jamfiles that refer to definitions like `SubDir` from the `Jambase` file, don't bother trying to use *bjam*/*b2*. Use *ft-jam* instead!

**Long answer** with some more background info:

At work I tried to build an old software package (Ingres DBMS 10.1) from
source over two weeks. It contained `Jamfile` and `Jamrules` files
in its tree structure, so I concluded that I would have to use *bjam*/*b2*
to get things going. The project's documentation wasn't specific enough
about this point as it turned out.

I had one major problem, the `Jamfiles` would use a lot of definitions
from the "`Jambase`" file, like "`SubDir`" a.s.o. Everytime I started the
build, I would get the error "`unknown rule`", as you can also see in the
question.

I finally decided to give an older Jam version a try, and voila: with
`ft-jam` v2.5.2 the project compiled flawlessly without any further ado. Yay!

So, basically everything was fine now and I could use `ft-jam` for my
purposes. But I still wondered whether I could also use bjam/b2 for the
compile. What is the purpose of the internal Jambase definition ("+"
file) and the "`-f`" option in bjam? Is it only for bootstrapping b2
itself, or can I use it while running b2? If yes, how do I activate it?

In the end, I wrote to the `boost-build` mailing list and got the following answer:

> b2 is not a drop-in replacement for Perforce Jam. Using ft-jam is the
>   correct option.
>
> The current Jambase is only used for bootstrapping Boost.Build. Older
>   versions of b2 had a copy of the original Jambase which would be
>   activated if the executable was named something other than b2/bjam.
>   Even so, I don't recommend using it as it was completely unmaintained.

[Link to mail thread](https://lists.boost.org/boost-build/2018/10/30012.php)